# Why Does my VM Keep Vanishing?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-memory

I have a Windows XP SP3 Professional OS running on a Dell Optiplex GX270. When I'm working with Visual Studio Express (a programming IDE), Google SketchUp, or any other resource-heavy program, my virtual memory takes a nose dive within about ten minutes of launching the program, and I get one of those notifications that Windows is adjusting the VM.

If I attempt to run two of these types of programs at the same time, my VM drops down to nothing, and I have to hard-reboot.

What is wrong, and how do I fix this? It is getting really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a lot of VM, its likely your system doesn't have enough real RAM.  You can increase the amount of VM available; but I suspect performance sucks as well - that would make it worse.  How much RAM is installed?

To understand this better, can you fire up Performance Monitor and take a look at the  Hard page Faults counter which you fire up and use one of these tools?  If it is high and continuous, you likely need RAM.

Comment: I found that the VM was set to custom instead of system managed. Changing it back to system managed kept it from running out anymore. Nevertheless, the system is painfully slow, so I opted to buy a new computer (thus giving me a better processor AND more RAM) TY!